# Dynamic crosstab grid values

Tags: sql, ms-access, crosstab

I'm very new to the world of Access and have been tasked with attempting to modify an existing database to add in a new report. I've been trying to find some form of an example of what I have been tasked with trying to create but to no avail. I have attached a picture of what my boss would like this report to look like:

[image: 1]

WCI-1 etc. are training courses, these are currently being stored as a massive list linking the employee ID to the course ID. Final A,B,C are skill levels where the first x number of courses are shared across all three but there are some extra courses which are required for levels A and B, currently the max number of courses is 20 the fewest is 5 but there are going to be more added in the future and this needs to be able to take those in without issues. I would prefer to not have to build all these tables manually because there are a few hundred different tables that this query needs to be able to create. in the grid the green box means they have taken the course and the red means they haven't, my boss would like that there not be any values in the grid just the colours to make it more visual. I have attached some sample data here which is from the select query I have to pull the data based on the selected division and skill for the report.

| EmployeeID | Name | CourseID | CourseName | visionID | DivName | Skillname | SkillID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 452 | AR | 687 | LNG-1 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 452 | AR | 687 | LNG-1 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 452 | AR | 1155 | WCI-1201 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 452 | AR | 1203 | 5 Why Training | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 452 | AR | 1235 | WCI-1223 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 452 | AR | 1181 | WCI-1119 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 452 | AR | 1155 | WCI-1201 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 452 | AR | 1077 | WCI-1139 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 452 | AR | 1060 | WCI-1120 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 309 | BC | 1235 | WCI-1223 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 309 | BC | 1077 | WCI-1139 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 309 | BC | 1060 | WCI-1120 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 309 | BC | 1181 | WCI-1119 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 309 | BC | 1155 | WCI-1201 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 309 | BC | 687 | LNG-1 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 309 | BC | 687 | LNG-1 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 398 | JL | 1181 | WCI-1119 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 398 | JL | 1235 | WCI-1223 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 398 | JL | 1060 | WCI-1120 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 398 | JL | 1155 | WCI-1201 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 398 | JL | 1211 | Final Assembly | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 398 | JL | 1155 | WCI-1201 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 398 | JL | 687 | LNG-1 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 398 | JL | 1077 | WCI-1139 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 498 | LT | 1155 | WCI-1201 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 498 | LT | 1060 | WCI-1120 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 498 | LT | 1077 | WCI-1139 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 498 | LT | 1235 | WCI-1223 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 498 | LT | 1181 | WCI-1119 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 498 | LT | 1235 | WCI-1223 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 498 | LT | 687 | LNG-1 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 498 | LT | 1235 | WCI-1223 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 495 | LYT | 1235 | WCI-1223 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 495 | LYT | 1077 | WCI-1139 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 495 | LYT | 687 | LNG-1 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 495 | LYT | 1060 | WCI-1120 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 495 | LYT | 1181 | WCI-1119 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |
| 495 | LYT | 1155 | WCI-1201 | 22 | VS1 Assembly | AVS1-Leadhand-B | 75 |

If anyone could let me know if this is even possible because the more and more I look into this it seems like this may be impossible or if it is it is way beyond my capabilities. If it is possible could you offer some suggestions as to where I would even start.

Comment: see [Make summary data easier to read by using a crosstab query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8).

Comment: Not showing any values in the grid. Edit question to show sample raw data as text tables. How many possible training courses?

Comment: @June7 I updated the question with sample data, the number of courses and mentioned the grid values let me know if that answers your questions or if you need more information

Comment: Data should be a text table, not an image. This makes it easier for us to pull data into a db. What field are the WC headers coming from? Why would you remove course names? And names without any other identifying data such as Address, SSN, BD are just as obscure as "Mickey Mouse".

Comment: However, reduce the names to just alias values in your sample.

Comment: @June7 just updated the quetion, had to split the table in two due to width limitations. I shortened the names to initials and removed the name of the courses but left the numbers in (course names have product names and such in them that aren't public yet). the WC headers are coming from a table in the DB that stores all the courses required for all levels of a specific skill

Comment: Setting textbox to not display data but to show color is fairly simple with textbox properties and Conditional Formatting. Building a CROSSTAB grouping by employee with course headers is also simple. The multi-line header is not. Nor is building a stable report based on dynamic CROSSTAB, which is a fairly common topic. An option is to use VBA to write data to a 'temp' table and use that as report RecordSource. Sample data produces 8 course headers. How many could be possible? Limit is 255 fields. This data arrangement just might not be practical for Access report. Could export query to Excel.

Comment: Most anything can be done with enough code. Whatever approach is taken, I expect significant VBA to be involved as well as report design specifics. Question really is too broad for a focused answer. Might want to seek a professional programmer.

Comment: Here is a short primer on CROSSTAB queries http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html

Comment: @June7 Thank you for all your help, I think an access professional programmer might be the way to go due to timelines.